# passing JSON encoded argument to a ruby script

Tags: php, ruby

i have a large php array encoded to JSON, and passing it to a ruby script.

however, it keeps throwing JSON::ParserError.... it is confused by the numerous doublequotes and singlequotes in the array.

i ahve tried

escapeshellarg, escapeshellcmd ..... these are not working.

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***

`escapeshellcmd` did the trick. You just have to spell it out carefully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko This is the answer that the OP added.